# difference between pdfLaTeX and LaTeX outputs

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to render the following:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{er}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{folding}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{plothandlers}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{topaths}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
% Uncomment these lines for colored equations
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage[usenames]{color}
%\definecolor{myColor}{RGB}{0,0,255}
%\pagecolor{white}\color{myColor}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\draw (0 cm,1pt) -- (0 cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north,fill=white] {A};
\draw (0.5 cm,1pt) -- (0.5 cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north,fill=white] {B};
\draw (1 cm,1pt) -- (1 cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north,fill=white] {C};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

LaTeX ("This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)") outputs a malformed DVI with all letters crowded on top of each other, at the origin.

[image]

On the same Linux system ("This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian) (format=latex 2013.4.5)"), pdfLaTeX works great.

You can see I added any TikZ library that I could find. What do I need to do to make TikZ work?

Comment: How are you viewing the DVI output?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: The problem came to my attention first while using TextMaths, a LibreOffice extension. The output of my code in TexMaths is equally malformed when asking for SVG or PNG output, suggesting malfunctions on the common, early steps.
I used the debugger, found what commands are issued by TexMaths, issued the same command, and got a malformed DVI. I can see the problem in DVI files by opening them in Evince.

Comment: Most DVI previewers, based on Xdvi, don't have many graphics capabilities as regards to PostScript specials. I tried viewing the output with Xdvi and indeed the characters are garbled; but transforming it into PS and PDF gives correct rendering. DVIType doesn't show any error when run on the output DVI file, which means that the file is correct.

Comment: Indeed, the DVI is OK, as it is converted to the expected result by both dvips and dvipdf. It is mind-blowing that Okular, Evince, dvisvgm, and dvipng show an identically wrong picture. I guess that it is the same issue the Joseph Wright was aiming at. How do I credit you, guy?

Comment: dvisvgm does convert the given document correctly. However, the optional PostScript support must be enabled. If it's not, it leads to the mentioned result. So, just ensure that Ghostscript is installed and it's accessible by dvisvgm. See the dvisvgm website for more information about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most DVI previewers are based on Xdvi, which has very little capabilities with respect to PostScript specials. For instance, it can show a PostScript graphic (with the help of Ghostscript), but it can't rotate it.

TikZ under `latex` uses heavily Postscript specials, so it's near to impossible seeing correctly TikZ pictures with Xdvi and derived viewers.

On the other hand, running DVIType (the program the Knuth team at Stanford wrote for validating and interpreting DVI files) on the result of your MWE shows no problem, so the DVI is formally correct (the program ignores specials, however). Converting it to PDF with `dvips+ps2pdf` shows correct output.