# Why PNG do not appear in XDVI?

Tags: png, xdvi

I have a LaTeX file with several PNG files inside. They appear beautifully in the PDF file generated by pdflatex. However, XDVI shows only a red frame where there should be the images. Any idea how to fix this?

This is the relevant part of the preamble of my LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart} 
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,amscd}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

Comment: Because `xdvi` is only able to show in a limited way some EPS files.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107222/difference-between-pdflatex-and-latex-outputs

Comment: In case it is important for some reason, you can use bmpp (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bmpp)  for converting bitmaps to eps format

Comment: EPSs are too big for my needs (10x the size of the PNGs). Thanks!